# Angular Material Datepicker Selection Strategy - how to get value of selected date range

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular13, angular-material-datetimepicker

I'm trying to create a table which will display some info. The columns will be dynamically changing according to the selected date range.

I'm using *Date range picker with custom a selection strategy* from Angular Material Documentation ([link](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#date-range-picker-selection-strategy)), but I don't know how can I get values of each day that is within selected range.
Here's how it works: [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/uc17u2--run?file=src/app/date-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.ts)

My code is pretty much the same as in doc example:

HTML:

```
<div class="datepick">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
      <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
      <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

.TS:

```
@Injectable()
export class FiveDayRangeSelectionStrategy<D> implements MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy<D> {
  constructor(private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>) {}

  selectionFinished(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    return this._createFiveDayRange(date);
  }

  createPreview(activeDate: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    return this._createFiveDayRange(activeDate);
  }

  private _createFiveDayRange(date: D | null): DateRange<D> {
    if (date) {
      const start = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, -2);
      const end = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(date, 2);
      return new DateRange<D>(start, end);
    }

    return new DateRange<D>(null, null);
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-view',
  templateUrl: './table-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-view.component.css'],
  providers: [{
      provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
      useClass: FiveDayRangeSelectionStrategy,
      },
      { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' },
    ],})
export class TableViewComponent{}
```

Any form of help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled on the same problem but could figure out a way.

The way i see it you have 2 options, either you do it like in the Angular Material Documentation via a FormGroup or you just bidirectionally bind a variable and listen on the close.

```
<mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
  <input [(ngModel)]="this.from" matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
  <input [(ngModel)]="this.thru" matEndDate placeholder="End date">
</mat-date-range-input>
```

and somewhere you put in your picker with the close listener...

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-date-range-picker #picker (closed)="changed(picker)"></mat-date-range-picker>
```

in your component you can now listen and output your variables (in my case input variables).

```
@Input() from !: Date;
@Input() thru !: Date;
changed(picker: MatDateRangePicker<any>) {
  console.log("changed");
  console.log(this.from);
  console.log(this.thru);
}
```

Have fun coding!

EDIT: removed useless style stuff.

EDIT2: variables + clarification